# Rails Logger -Rails logrotate automatically

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i am using like this, 
config.logger = Logger.new(Rails.root.join('log', "#{Rails.env}.log"), 10, 10*1024). Its working perfectly.It clear the log the file reach 10240bytes.

i taken back up of the log file, the name of the file is "development.log.0","development.log.1".. Now i want "development.log.0.2012-09-24"(that is i want to add Time.now at the end of the file name. Can any one help me??

Answer (score 1):

This is entirely dependent upon the stack you're deploying to, but I'm of the opinion that rotating logs shouldn't be a concern of your Rails app.  I would recommend doing this at the OS level using `logrotate` (if you're on *nix) scheduled daily via `cron`.

http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
config.logger = Logger.new(Rails.root.join('log', "#{Rails.env}.log.#{Date.today.to_s}"), 10, 10*1024)
```

Comment: for default development.log file should be "development.log", from next one on wards i want "development.log.0.2012-09-24 ", if i execute the above one means the default one also changing.